# How to use unspecified array dimensions in blocks?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, systemmodeler

Using unspecified array dimensions (`:`) is an essential feature to design flexible components for reuse. I am well [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29187792/5363743) that the actual dimension has to be fixed when the model is compiled. To my knowledge binding a variable with unspecified array dimensions to one that has clearly defined dimensions should suffice.

So I am a bit confused why the following `model Test` will not validate in either `OpenModelica` or the `Wolfram System Modeler`:

```
package VectorFunctions

  model Test
      VectorSum converter "Component taking the sum of a vector input";
      InformationSource source "Vector input";
    equation
      connect( source.y, converter.u );
  end Test;

  block VectorSum "Take the sum of an input with unspecified dimension"
      Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u[:];
      Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y;
    equation
      y = sum(u);
  end VectorSum;

  block InformationSource "Provide some vector output"
      Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y[3];
    equation
      y = ones( 3 );
  end InformationSource;

end VectorFunctions;
```

**How can something like this be done then?**

Comment: Note, that I cross-posted a similiar question on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1706682).

Comment: I updated my code to provide `connectors` for a clean `connect` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been given (inofficial) [feedback on Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1706682) by someone from Wolfram MathCore (e.g. the developers of the System Modeler):

> *Hi, I agree with your interpretation, I think we should support it. I have filed a bug to keep track of this issue internally, unfortunately I do not see any work around. We will come back to you when we have fixed this problem.*

So, hopefully flexbile array sizes will be supported for `blocks` as they are for `functions`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the Modelica Spec does not specify, that vector sizes can be automatically detected from connections, so the tools don't support that.

I think you have to set the vector size somehow by yourself, e.g. with a parameter which is set in your Test model as follows:

```
  model Test
      VectorSum converter(nu=size(source.y, 1)) "Pass in the vector size";
      InformationSource source "Vector input";
  equation 
      connect(source.y, converter.u);
  end Test;

  block VectorSum "Take the sum of an input with unspecified dimension"
      Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput u[nu];
      parameter Integer nu(min=0)=0;
      output Real y;
  equation 
      y = sum(u);
  end VectorSum;
```

Note that Dymola complains in your example code that connect statements can only be applied to connectors. Therefore I changed `input Real` to `Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput`(and similar in `InformationSource`)

Comment: Actually the [Modelica specs](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33.pdf) in my opinion are not clear about this:  *Section 10.2 Flexible Array Sizes* simply points at *Section 12.4.5* where this is discussed for `functions` (which allow the use as presented here for inputs). Since `blocks` share some familiarity with `functions` as is pointed out in the specs I am still not seeing a good reason why this should not work out.